# Appropriate use for boost::shared_ptr?

Tags: c++, pointers, boost, shared-ptr

A question about `boost::shared_ptr` here:

I have 3 Classes.

`A` is some kind of Main class which is responsible to manage everything.

`B` is a class which just has functions to do some work.

`Dispatcher` is just a class which wraps around a seperate thread, which gets the work from Instaces of `B`done in this thread.

So it is kinda working like this: `A` has an instance of `Dispatcher`. Now on occassion `A` generates an instance of `B` and passes it to the dispatcher.

The important part is, that `B` needs to call `A::callback()` when it's done. This is why `B` gets a reference to A in it's constructor ( see code below )

A.hpp

```
class A : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
public:
    A();
    void sendB();
    void callback();
private:
    Dispatcher m_Dispatcher;
};
```

B.hpp

```
class B
{
public:
    B(boost::shared_ptr<A> ptr);
    boost::shared_ptr<A> m_PointerToA;
 /* Some other functions */
};
```

Dispatcher.hpp

```
class Dispatcher
{
public:
     void run();
     void dispatch(boost::shared_ptr<B> b);
private:
     void doWork();
     boost::thread m_Thread;  
};
```

A.cpp

```
A::A()
{
    m_Dispatcher.run();
}
void A::sendB()
{
    boost::shared_ptr ptr_B;
    ptr_B.reset(new B(this->shared_from_this);
    m_Dispatcher.dispatch(ptr_B);
}
```

B.cpp

```
B::B(boost::shared_ptr<A> ptr) :
    : m_PointerToA(ptr)
{
}
```

main_example.cpp

```
int main()
{
     A instanceA;
     while(true)
     {
          instanceA.sendB();
          /* Do some other stuff */
     }
     return 0;
}
```

So my question is:

**Is it reasonable to use boost::shared_ptr for this purpose?**

I am not sure if the `shared_ptr` is the right thing to go here. My problem is, that I don't know what happens exactly when I call the constructor from `B` and pass it the `this` pointer. Now according to `shared_ptr` I would assume that `m_PointerToA` takes ownership of `A`. But this would mean that when the work in the `Dispatcher` is done and my instance of `B` gets deleted it would also delete the reference to `m_PointerToA` which would actually mean it kills the object itself despite the fact there is an actual instance of `A` in the main loop.

**Update:**

Added some code and updated question itself to make it more clear.

Comment: You don't want to use `shared_ptr` across thread boundaries.  This is one place where the semantics of `std::auto_ptr` really shine; once you've passed the pointer to the other thread, you can't access it in the original thread.

Comment: `boost::shared_ptr` is actually thread safe, in the sense that you can rely on the reference counting to be in a safe state.

Comment: @JamesKanze But the pointer I pass is actually a `this` pointer. So actually I don't do anything with the "pointer" in particular. But of course some code in the instance from `this` is still running in the main thread. I actually just wanted to use the `shared_ptr` so I don't come in any troubles by losing references. I would have also no problem with using a raw pointer...

Comment: I have a couple of questions. You are newing your B instance in `initClassB` but how is that referenced? If you are storing it in A, how are you doing that? You are passing it to a thread you say, so is that being referenced solely from the that thread?

The question is really about how you want A to die. Do you want it to go down with the other thread? As it stands the B is the sole owner of A, and it will die with B. In that case I would also recommend using an auto_ptr and it makes it very clear who owns the A instance.

Comment: @Dennis Gonna update the question so it gets more clear ( I omitted some code when I first wrote it =

Comment: @Toby In which case, you have to be very, very careful.  And `shared_ptr` probably doesn't buy you anything (except extra complexity) over a raw pointer.  (Every time I've needed to pass `this` to another thread, the object has been on the stack anyway.)

Comment: @JamesKanze So in this particular case it would be appropriate to just use a raw pointer?

Comment: @Toby Most likely.  To be sure, one would have to see the complete context, but unless there is some particular reason for using `shared_ptr`, raw pointer is better.  And particularly when threading, I'd avoid `shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is okay to just copy/assign a `shared_ptr`, it will only increase the reference count.

In your example, `shared_from_this()` will create a (here: temporary) `shared_ptr` from the `weak_ptr` that is hold by `this` (ref count 1), so when you assign/copy-construct `m_PointerToA`, the reference count will increase temporarily to 2 before the ctor returns and the temporary object will be destroyed, decreasing the reference count to 1 again (the shared_ptr is "aware" of the one instance in your `B` object).

So, yes, if B is deleted, it will destroy A in this case (as the reference count drops to 0).

Your concern

> This would mean if my Instance of B is deleted, it would also delete m_PointerToA which would also kill my instance of A . Of course my original instance of `A` is held elsewhere.

only shows that if you plan/need/intend to keep a pointer to the instance of `A` for further usage, you should do so with a `shared_ptr` as well instead of a raw pointer.  If you have control of `A`'s interface, the easiest way would be a [named constructor](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Named_Constructor) like this:

```
class A : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<A> {
    public:
        static boost::shared_ptr<A> create();

        void initClassB();
        // ....
    private:
        A();
        A( const A & other );
        A& operator=( const A & rhs );

};

boost::shared_ptr<A> A::create() {
    return boost::shared_ptr<A>( new A() );
}
```

Then, even if your instance of `B` is deleted, the instance of `A` will still survive because the reference count of the `shared_ptr` is still (at least) 1.

Comment: Okay I see why your solution would really make sure that A will not be deleted because the reference count will at least be 1. But then I would like to know: Someone ( for example a main function or another class ) needs to call the `A::create()` method - so if instead of using your solution this main function would just create a normal instance of A I could lose it while `B` is getting deleted? So A would also get deleted despite the fact that there is an actual instance of that object?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "despite the fact that there is an actual instance of that object". The `shared_ptr` will destroy the instance if the reference drops to 0. If there is only one `shared_ptr` to `A` in `B`, yes, destroying B will destroy that instance of `A`. If your are referring to A somewhere via a raw pointer, there is no way to prevent this. But that's why you should smart pointers consistently (don't use raw pointers to objects that are managed by smart pointers).

Comment: With the example above, the main function would not be able to create a "normal" instance (raw pointer) of `A` because there is no constructor available/accessible (your compiler will report an error if you try). The only way to construct an instance of `A` is by calling `A::create()`

Comment: I added `main_example.cpp` in the question to make it more clear. I just say, somewhere I get an actual instance of object A - now this means I would not use a `create()` method like you mentioned - resulting in the fact that my Ref Count could drop to 0 when B gets deleted?

Comment: Or let's ask my question in other words: If I derive my `class A` from `boost::enable_shared_from_this<A>` that doesnt implicitly make a ref count of 1?

Comment: @Toby Well, if the Named-Constructor idiom is suitable for you, you could not create instances of `A` on the stack anymore. The only way to create instances of `A` would be calling `A::create()`. Everything else will be denied by the compiler. Regarding `enabled_shared_from_this`, no, it will not make a ref count of 1. It only holds a `weak_ptr` (which can be converted to a `shared_ptr`). Otherwise, `A` would never be destroyed since the ref count would never drop to zero.

Comment: Okay now I get it! Thanks for your answers, this cleared things up pretty much for me!

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing particular wrong with this design. However I would prefer to instead use `boost::function<>` & `boost::bind`. It gives you way better flexibility for the callback and doesn't tie B as tightly to A. Of course you still have to be vary of the usual threading caveats.

Comment: +1. Good advice. Also, if you have perfect control over the lifetime of your instances, you could simply store a *reference* to your `A`. If you don't need `B` to be assignable of course.

Comment: Yeah I also thought about doing it a bit more generic, but in my first attempt I just wanted it to work. So there is no actualy problem with using the boost::shared_ptr?